# Why doesn't this simple Go server run in Azure App Services?

Tags: azure, go, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have this code in `server.go` :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "You just browsed page (if blank you're at the root): %s", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT"), nil)
}
```

and this `web.config` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="d:\home\site\wwwroot\go\bin\go.exe" 
                      arguments="run d:\home\site\wwwroot\server.go" 
                      startupTimeLimit="60">
            <environmentVariables>
              <environmentVariable name="GOROOT" value="d:\home\site\wwwroot\go" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Both of these files are in the `d:\home\site\wwwroot` directory of an Azure App Service. I also have the `1.13.3` version of the x64 Windows go runtime installed (unzipped from `go1.13.3.windows-amd64.zip`) in `d:\home\site\wwwroot\go`.

When I browse to `fwWebApi.azurewebsites.net/hello` it times out.

I got this sample from http://www.wadewegner.com/2014/12/4-simple-steps-to-run-go-language-in-azure-websites/ which is admittedly a few years old. But I want to be able to run a Go web application in Azure App Services.

Can anyone suggest what I can do?

Comment: Are you ports configured correctly to allow inbound traffic on port 80?

Comment: I believe so. I have never had to set anything specific for port 80 when creating an App Service.

Comment: Using `go run` like this means that every time the handler starts it's going to *build and run* your code. Go isn't PHP or Ruby, you shouldn't be using `go run` for pretty much anything. You should `go build` on your workstation or build server, and deploy the compiled binary to your server (which doesn't need Go installed at all).

Comment: @Adrian thanks -- I changed the `web.config` file to call `server.exe` which I built locally and copied up. That gave me a 502.

Comment: This definitely used to work for me a few months ago. I've just returned to the project and suddenly this isn't working. Still trying to debug. Hopefully won't have to go down the container route. Will update here if I get anywhere.

Comment: @bobuva Turns out I had a missing html file that caused my program to break. The only way I found that out is going into kudu command prompt and running my executable manually. If you do that, does it give you any clues to the 502? (I was also getting 502s)

Comment: Maybe this helps: Running Go Applications directly on Azure App Service https://blog.hdev.io/posts/running-go-applications-directly-on-azure-app-service/

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest you use a docker image to run your non supported language on azure app services:

Supported languages  ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, Java, Ruby, Node.js, PHP, or Python

Github: https://github.com/AnassKartit/helloworld-golang

Docker Image
https://hub.docker.com/r/anasskartit/hello-world-golang

First Run will take some time as it downloads the image you can check the logs

[image]

[image]

Result
[image]

Comment: If that's what I have to do, I'll try that. I just want to see if it is at all possible to call standard Go code directly in an App Service.

Comment: Hey Anass, Thanks very much for the sample! I'll give it a try.

Comment: This one is old though https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/running-go-applications-on-azure-app-service

Comment: Rather than mark this as completed, I want to keep this open since I would very much like to get a Go program to run without a container. Still wondering why a self-contained, native Go program does not work in Azure App Service.

Comment: Hey, @bobuva, here is an example / guide https://blog.hdev.io/posts/running-go-applications-directly-on-azure-app-service/. 
Credit to the author.